# 1С 8.3. Как при изменении какой-нибудь ячейки ТЧ найти нужный кусок кода?

Tags: 1с

Когда в `ТЧ` изменяю для примера сумму, то не могу сразу найти его точное месторасположение (т.е. значение данной суммы), их месторасположение окажется либо в общих модулях, например в `дкДокументы`, либо в каких-нибудь `регистрах` (только методом тыка нашел, тратя много времени).

Даже `отладка кода` не особо помогает, либо бесконечная трассировка (погружение в разные уровни документов все дальше и дальше), либо еще что-то.

С "`замером производительности`" та же история, куча строк, с методом тыка уходит куча времени.

Как сделать так, чтобы можно было быстро найти точное месторасположение значения любой ячейки в ТЧ? Какие способы для вас оптимальны при поиске нужного участка кода для целевой ячейки табличной части?

Answer (score 0):

Откройте соответствующую ***Форму Документа***, затем станьте курсором мыши на нужную ***Колонку*** табличной части документа; *Справа в свойствах*, Вы увидите ***список событий*** и назначенные этим событиям процедуры;